# UIPageViewController with a frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with two pages. The first one is a custom `UIViewController` and the second one is a `UITableViewController`. The app has a `UINavigationController` and a Tab Bar.

I'd like to set a frame or border around the `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController`. I have tried several solutions, but no one fits to my problem.

I tried to use this code inside my `UIPageViewController`:

```
CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 10.0, 10.0);
self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;
```

The frame is good, but when the user changes the page the frame doesn't move.

I tried another solution, which is to set the border around the `UITableView` this way:

```
CALayer *layer = self.tableView.layer;

[layer setFrame:CGRectMake(52, 52, 50, 50)];
[layer setBorderWidth:52.0];
[layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.8 alpha: 1.0] CGColor]];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

In this case the frame is too big, but is an example. The problem is that the frame is always over the table view and covers the text.

I only need a frame around a custom view and a table view that moves when the user changes the page.

Let me know if you need additional information.

**UPDATE**

I tried the solutions sugested by LoVo and Mahesh Agrawal but is the same I tried and the problem can be seen in the image:

[image: border over table]

As you can see the border is over the header (again the border is bigger to see the problem).

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you

```
[self.tableView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[self.tableView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

try once. and same for your another view.

UPDATE

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 2.0f;

self.tableView.frame = CGRectInset(self.frame, -borderWidth, -borderWidth);
self.tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I updated the question to show the problem with this solution.

Comment: I've got the same issue with this solutions. The border is always over the tableView. And I can't use self.frame, I tried with self.tableView.frame or self.view.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. I updated the question to show the problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change the size of your tableview frame.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(1,1,self.view.frame.size.width - 2,self.view.frame.size.height - 2);
//or whatever width your border should have

self.pageViewController.view.frame = frame;

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the frame doesn't move with the page when you change the page inside a pageviewController.